# How to make REST APIs calls for APIs I have on my Backend

Tags: node.js, http, express, heroku, request

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to use READ operation from the CRUD I developed which means that I have to invoke a HTTP request (Using RequestJS for example). And then use the response coming from the READ to do some other things.

READ Operation

```
router.get('/api/example', function(request, response, next) {
   //MongoDB Code to fetch a certain doc
   exampleModel.find(request.query.key)
   .then(function(doc) {response.status(200).json(doc)})
});
```

So As you see I respond to the user with the json. What I want to do is to use this route and get the JSON response to use in another function. A middleware in a sense.

Other function

```
function useRead(){
    //Make an HTTP Request using localhost:3000/api/example?key=123
    useJSON(doc)
}
```

I understand that I could use requestJS to get the response. But the problem is does it make sense to make a request to localhost:3000/api/example?key=123. and also when i deploy the application on Heroku for example, that URL would not make sense and I think would crash the application as it should use www.myDomain.com instead of localhost:3000, so how do I solve this problem.

I tried to be concise as possible, Sorry if somethings are not clear.

Comment: Please clarify where the function useRead will be defined.  Will it be written in the same server which has the end point /api/example, or is it going to be in another server(a middleware server), or is it in client side javascript.

Comment: It will be on the same server

Comment: why don't you move the callback of your route into another function, that you could use in your route definition AND in that another function that you need to use it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may already have a solution at your hand. Assuming you are developing using an MV framework like react or angular or just with plain javascript you could call API with relative route given that you render the front-end part using express static inside the same express app.

```
router.get('/api/example', function(req, res){
    exampleFunction(req.query, function(err, doc){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        response.status(200).json(doc);
    })
});
```

So inside the web app, you could call API as below.

**app.js** (Or any other file where app runs)

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + 'public')); // assuming static files are placed inside public folder
```

```
async function getAPI() {
   try {
     const res = await axios.post('/path/to/api'); // Doesn't require server remote url as it is relative
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
   }
}
```

Now the front end can call its own APIs like that.

**Extra tip** (Using promise call inside route)

```
...
const axios = require('axios'); // I am using axios. Use whatever you require
...
...
route.get('/path/to/api', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/remote/api/);
    res.send(res.data)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(401).send(err.data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on comment by [Gonzalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437934/gonzalo), please move out the logic inside the api route to a function, export the function to use anywhere in the server.

Example:

```
//Page with read operation

module.exports = {
    router : router,
    exampleFunction : exampleFunction
}

router.get('/api/example', function(req, res){
    exampleFunction(req.query, function(err, doc){
        if(err)
            console.log(err);
        response.status(200).json(doc);
    })
});

function exampleFunction(query, next) {
   //MongoDB Code to fetch a certain doc
   exampleModel.find(query.key)
   .then(function(err,doc) {
       if(err)
           return next(err,null);
       return next(null, doc);
   })
}



//page with read call

var readPage = require('readPage');


function useRead(){
    readPage.exampleFunction({query:{key:'abcd'}},function(err, doc){
        if(err)
             console.log(err);
        useJSON(doc)
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you dude. Although it wasn't the solution for my problem. I got to tell you it helped me solve another issue I had with my code.